# react startkit to firebase I really don't know why this things.. happen

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, firebase, vision

Manifest merger failed : `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0] /Users/kwon/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7503370eda9be985ee76d9816836e010/firebase-iid-19.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml` as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a `minSdk` of at most 14,
        or increase this project's `minSdk` version to at least 16,
        or use `tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid"` to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **build.gradle** under **android/app/**

and change `minSdkVersion` it might be 14 change it to given

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Comment: I love you guys I take a two hour for what is wrong with my project thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error code is self explanatory.

You have defined the minimum sdk version of your Android project to be 14 and the Firebase library needs the minimum to be 16.

It also tells you how to fix it in the error:

`Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16, or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)`

To raise the minimumSdkVersion of the project, go to your application's build.gradle file.
Or at the bottom of the file, change the Firebase dependency.

Comment: i don't think firebase dependency work under 16 sdk

Comment: I love you guys I take a two hour for what is wrong with my project thank you

Comment: @Ashish - as stated, you can use tools:overrideLibrary to force usage, but that will probably lead to runtime crashes...